# Unterminated jsx content while using browserroutes?

Tags: reactjs, routes, jsx, react-router-dom, mern

I want to route through react components in an app using browserroutes and routes of react-router-dom but geing an error

**Error:**

```
Line 44:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

  42 |              <Route path='/edit' component={EditExpensePage} />
  43 |          </div>
> 44 |      </BrowserRouter>
     |                      ^
  45 | );
```

**__File:__**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';


const HelpPage =()=>{
return(
    <div>
        This is from HelpPage
    </div>
);
}

const EditExpensePage =() =>{
return(
    <div>
        This is from EditExpensePage
    <div>
);
}
const routes=(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path='/' component={HelpPage} exact={true}/>
            <Route path='/edit' component={EditExpensePage} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have tried it making as a stateless component(routes) and rendering it as a react component but it didn't worked and was still giving an error of unterminaed jsx content

Comment: Maybe its a typo or unclosed tag. Can You show us the whole code?

Comment: now you can check the code

Comment: The problem is the closing `<div>` in `EditExpensePage`, which should be `</div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
const EditExpensePage =() =>{
return(
    <div>
        This is from EditExpensePage
    </div>
);
```